# MermaidJS styles appears odd in Chrome Mobile

Tags: javascript, browser, mermaid, android-chrome

I have used mermaidJS for an APP to show the flow-diagrams. The library looks quite good in Chrome & Firefox in Web. However, it looks quite silly when rendered in Chrome Android. What's puzzling is the styles look good on android-firefox as well.

I verified the mermaid page and it confirmed my issue. If you try to render the mermaid demo page https://mermaidjs.github.io/demos.html, it looks OK in all browsers except android-chrome.

This issue has been listed in the github issues list, but hasn't been resolved. https://github.com/knsv/mermaid/issues/816

Any work-around for this? I am building a PWA, hence it is important for the flow-chart to render well in web and mobile browsers